# How similar output do mathptmx and Times New Roman create?

Tags: fonts

How similar output do `mathptmx` and 'Times New Roman' (in Word) create? Times New Roman is the required font type (no comment) at a University for theses... Is there big differences between the two?

I've already checked unsing `lipsum`, they look indistinguishable. Is there specific characters or situations where they are notably different?

Comment: Don't worry. Nobody *requiring* Times for theses will be able to spot any difference.

Comment: @egreg So there're no obvious differences? Should I delete my question or you'll add this as an "official" :) answer.

Comment: There's no such thing as *the* Times New Roman font. Different machines can have different clones of it.

Comment: @egreg I did not know that, very useful info. Will you add an answer?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is what I get from the following input (compile with XeLaTeX); they are all the Times-like fonts I have on my machine. The fourth line in each item shows the internal name of the font, so to see that they are all different.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\newcommand\alphabet{ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz 0123456789\\
\expandafter\texttt\expandafter{\fontname\font}}

\begin{document}
\begin{itemize}
\fontspec{Times}
\item Times\\\alphabet

\fontspec{Times New Roman}
\item Times New Roman\\\alphabet

\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ptm}\selectfont
\item Mathptmx\\\alphabet

\fontencoding{OT1}\fontfamily{ntxr}\selectfont
\item NewTX\\\alphabet

\end{itemize}
\end{document}
```

Are you able to spot any difference?

[image]

Comment: I can't. But I don't really know anything about fonts. I wasn't sure if there was anything else than characters in a font definition. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: Just because `\fontname` is different, doesn't mean the fonts are different. One needs to further look up `ptmr7t`. It is a virtual font that points to a `ptmr8r.tfm` which can then be looked up in `pdftex.map` (or wherever xetex gets its mapping info). The same with `txr`. In fact, both ultimately use `NimbusRomNo9L-Regu`. Nimbus and Times New Roman fonts tend to differ mostly in italics, where the letters f, g, i, j, u, and z are noticeably different (especially z). In the upright fonts, only the f's seem different.

Comment: @Dan It's quite difficult to follow each and every virtual font; actually different TeX distributions might resolve differently the Type1 font associated to a raw TFM file.

Comment: @egreg That was my point, that the font tfm name was not decisive. I am pretty sure the last two in the figure are the same font and the first two are different from each other. More than that I wouldn't say.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you are doing extensive math... they are for purposes of the author identical. The Mathptmx loads the times math fonts however whereas the Times New Roman fonts only use the Computer Modern math font. If you are going for uniformity - I would recommend the Mathptmx  package as it is made for that purpose.

Comment: In my opinion the `newtxmath` package offers a superior math environment than `mathptmx` for typeset maths in Times.