# Can I replace the accents somehow?

Tags: fonts, accents

[I've asked about](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145511/how-similar-output-do-mathptmx-and-times-new-roman-create) how similar is `mathptmx` to Times New Roman. I have a fine answer for that, but I forgot to mention I have a few accented characters... They doesn't look similar at all to the desired.

Can I fix the accented characters somehow (all the other characters are fine)? I have no idea whether this is even possible...

What I wanted (sg similar would do):

[image]

What I've got with `mathptmx`:

[image]

Example code what we have for the last one.

```
\documentclass[doc,a5paper,landscape,12pt]{apa6}

\PassOptionsToPackage{chapternumber=Huordinal}{magyar.ldf}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{t1enc}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newgeometry{
    margin=2.5cm,
    bindingoffset=0.5cm,
    headheight=2cm,
}

\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ\\
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz\\
0123456789\\
ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰáéíóöőúüű

\end{document}
```

(yes, Hungarian has a bunch of accented characters...)

Or can I use Times New Roman, apa6 and Hungarian anyhow? (some of the commenters mentioned LuaLaTeX and XeTeX but I could get them work together)

Comment: what font encoding are you using? (Please always provide a complete document, then we wouldn't need to ask)

Comment: The lower one looks like Times, not Times New Roman (I have both installed on a Mac and I just compared).  But is the effort you are putting into this really worth it?  Will the people looking at your thesis really notice the difference and if they do, will they really care?

Comment: @Szabolcs it is a thesis requirement to "use Times New Roman" and to use APA6... they're picky as hell... noone wants to risk these differences (they would rather write in MSWord)...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I've added my code, but I'm not good with font settings.

Comment: It is hard to believe these thesis requirements are really requirements (my thesis was done on a typewriter and I still passed:-) But anyway if you are really that concerned why don't you use xetex and use the system installation of times new roman exactly.

Comment: @masu If you are so concerned about the identity of the font, why not compile your document with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX and actually *use* Times New Roman?

Comment: @AlanMunn Because LuaLaTeX has it's problems with Hungarian (magyar) language settings... I don't know that about XeLaTeX... If you'd supply an answer about using apa6 and Times New Roman with Hungarian setting I'd be greatful (I've never used XeTeX (or LuaLaTeX)).

Comment: @DavidCarlisle It's hard to believe for me too... It's not a university of technology (or similar) (not mine) but a medical one... which is pedantic with no connection to the real world, I guess... :)
I don't know about XeTeX, but LuaLaTeX doesn't support Hungarian. Does apa6 and Hungarian work with XeTeX? I'll add this to my question as an answer possibility.

Comment: If an institution fails a thesis because of the slope of the accents on capital letters, you've got to question the institution. You say LuaLaTeX doesn't support Hungarian but that seems unlikely, it may be that the magyar babel option doesn't work in lualatex but that isn't the same thing.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Little late to question the institution when someone is trying to write the tesis... but they really can't do that now... shame.
Yes, that's the case, babel is the source of the problem.

Comment: @masu Yes, Hungarian works fine with XeTeX.  I remember I have typed some document in utf8 for use with XeTeX (though that was quite a while ago), and you can see from my name that I'm Hungarian :-)

Comment: Thanks for all the help, I'll tinker around for a while and try everything, then I'll probably answer or delete this question.

Comment: As far as I know Hungarian uses accents like in the second picture, rather than those in the first picture.

Comment: @egreg I've learnt vertical accents in elementary school, but "in the digital age" they became "vertical or tilted right" (the shape doesn't really matter - only that if it is a "line" or a dot)

Comment: At least it's not Comic Sans what they want...

Comment: @egreg The tiny difference in slant doesn't matter for as long as you know how to spell Erdős when writing papers `;-)` (unfortunately many mathematicians still don't).  Both are just fine in Hungarian.  They didn't teach me vertical accents in elementary school BTW.

Comment: I' ve just checked and MiKTeX-LuaLaTeX ignores all Hungarian accented characters, such as `\documentclass{article}\begin{document}őű\end{document}`. Loading `fontspec` alone fixes this.

Comment: And XeTeX behaves the same. No errors are caused by `\usepackage[magyar]{babel}`. It may depend on `magyar.ldf` version though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to all the help in the comments I managed to create a XeLaTeX document.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{apa6}

%\PassOptionsToPackage{chapternumber=Huordinal}{magyar.ldf}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text]{Times New Roman}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\shorttitle{}

\begin{document}

ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ

abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz

0123456789

ÁÉÍÓÖŐÚÜŰáéíóöőúüű

\end{document}
```

Comment: You should *not* use `inputenc` with XeLaTeX (and your file *must* be encoded as UTF8 not any other encoding.)

Comment: @AlanMunn thanks, I've used only to make a warning go away. I suppose it didn't change anything else.